# Receive Variable from Service Javascript - React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have a button element that invokes another javascript file in my workspace.

```
      <Button
        onClick={() =>
            SendRegister(
              {
                registrationType: 'email',
                latitude: 55,
                longitude: 100,
                distance: 100,
                email: 'email@testemail.com'
              }
            )
        }>
        Set Up Notifications
      </Button>
```

In the other javascript file, I am writing the information received to firebase:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import firebase from "./firebase";

    function SendRegister(props) {
      alert('in Send register');
      alert(JSON.stringify(props));
      var db = firebase.firestore();

      if (props.registrationType === 'email') {
        db.collection("emailAlerts")
          .add({
            email: props.email,
            latitude: props.latitude,
            longitude: props.longitude,
            distance: props.distance,
           status: "active"
          })
          .then(function(docRef) {
            return docRef.id;
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            return("Error adding document: " + error);
          });
    }

    }

    export default SendRegister;
```

In firebase I am seeing the records successfully write, however I am unsure how to get the returns of the function passed back to the script where I invoked the `onClick`.

I have tried wrapping the SendRegister function in a `useState` const such as `setStatus(SendRegister...` to capture the return but I receive an `undefined` back in the return. I looked up lifting up the state as well which makes sense for an element/component, but not sure how that fits into a function like `SendRegister`. I believe redux and `useContext` is an option, but I want to ensure there isn't a simpler way to pass variables up from one page to another that I'm not considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to get the return value `docRef.id` in the parent component. Since, the operation inside `SendRegister` is asynchronous, you should return a promise from `SendRegister` for which the parent component can listen to.

```
export default class componentName extends Component {

  async handleSendRegister(params){
    try {
      const docRefId = await SendRegister(params)

      // docRefId is now available here
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onClick={() =>
          this.handleSendRegister(
            {
              registrationType: 'email',
              latitude: 55,
              longitude: 100,
              distance: 100,
              email: 'email@testemail.com'
            }
        )
    }>
    Set Up Notifications
  </Button>
    )
  }
}
```

and the `SendRegister` should be a simple async function.

```
async function SendRegister(props) {
  try {
    if (props.registrationType === 'email') {

      const docRef = await db.collection("emailAlerts")
      .add({
        email: props.email,
        latitude: props.latitude,
        longitude: props.longitude,
        distance: props.distance,
       status: "active"
      })

      return docRef.id
    }

   } catch (error) {
      throw Error(error.message)
  }

}

export default SendRegister;
```

Comment: Thanks. I selected your answer, but I did have to modify this to use functional components and hooks for main component. If you could update the answer to include what the above would like in hooks (the only real change is async handleRegister in functional components must be async function handleRegister).With a hook example of updating the state such as setDocRefId.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback method on onClick handler like:

```
SendRegister(
          {
            registrationType: 'email',
            latitude: 55,
            longitude: 100,
            distance: 100,
            email: 'email@testemail.com',
            callback: ()=>{// code to executed on promise resolve}
          }
```

And you can call this function inside promise.then() as it will be part of props.